# Given a weighted undirected graph, how do I find a path which has the total weights close to a given value?

Tags: algorithm, graph, theory

Suppose I have a weighted, undirected graph. Each edge has a positive weight. I would like to find a simple path (no vertices appear in the path twice) from a given source node (s) to a target node (t) which has the total sum of weights close to a given value (P).

Even though it sounds like a well-studied problem, I couldn't find a satisfying solution. Many graph algorithms are aiming to find the shortest path (in a sense of steps or cost), but not to find the "matched" cost path.

A naive solution would be finding all paths from s to t, compute sum of weights for each path and select the one that is close to P. However, finding all paths between two nodes in a graph is known to be #P-hard.

A possible solution could be modified the A* algorithm, so that for each node in the frontier we get the cost from the root to that node (g), and estimate the cost from that node to the goal (h). Then instead of choosing a node with the smallest g+h, we choose a node with the smallest |P - (g+h)|. However, I am not sure if this is the best solution.

Another thought is inspired from the linear programming since the objective function of this problem is sum(weights of a path from s to t) - P = 0. I know the shortest path problem can be formed as a linear programming task but not sure how to formulate this problem as a one.

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: _"However, it's a NP-hard problem for finding all paths from two nodes."_ No. The notion of NP-hardness makes sense when we talk about decision problems; you're claiming that something that's not a decision problem is NP-hard; don't mix oranges and apples. What you probably wanted to say is that there are exponentially (exercise: exponential in which parameter? :-) many paths from `s` to `t`. BTW nice question.

Comment: The related __counting__ problem---how many simple paths are there between two vertices in a graph---is __#P__-hard ([reference](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/423/how-hard-is-counting-the-number-of-simple-paths-between-two-nodes-in-a-directed)). Didn't mean to be rude; I just had to get this off my chest. :-)  It's always good to make sure you know what you're talking about.

Comment: @blazs thanks for letting me know, it's always good to learn something new, I edited my question.

Comment: Just determining if there is a between two nodes with a given length is NP hard because it contains the Hamiltonian path problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is NP-hard via a reduction from the Hamiltonian path problem. In that problem, you are given a graph and a pair of nodes s and t and are asked whether there's a simple path from s to t that passes through all the nodes in the graph. You can solve the Hamiltonian path problem via your problem as follows:

- Assign each edge in the graph weight 1.
- Find the s-t simple path whose weight is as close to n-1 as possible, where n is the number of nodes in the graph.
- Returns whether this path has cost exactly n-1.

If the graph has a Hamiltonian path, then that path will have cost n-1. Otherwise, it doesn't, and the best path found will have a cost that's lower than n-1.